# How to make a Patch for the bottom Inner Fender

Tags: body-work, metal, fabrication

I am trying to figure out what is a good design for the bottom right inner fender patch:

OPTION A   (First Pic)

[image]

Technically,  I should put the patch on top of the arch (blue):

*But that would be more challenging as we dont have space to access the back of the inner fender*

OPTION B   (Second Pic)

[image]

I am thinking of putting the patch underneath (easier for metal forming):

Shown in orange and then tip the wheelarch as least one inch (for panel bonding) , shown in green

*The only issue is the tipped wheel arch won't sit as high as in the left side patch* (Third Pic)

[image]

Solutions:  I could bond another piece of metal on there to make it sit higher

or?

I do not know how to weld, I am panel bonding.

Thank you and have a great day!